# Sink on IIS SMTP Windows Server 2008 / 2008R2

Tags: iis, smtp, windows-server-2008

I need help. I wrote simple sink by sample in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998610.aspx. On IIS Smtp Windows server 2003 it work fine. But on IIS Smtp Windows Server 2008 or 2008R2 it don't work. I try other sample from Internet. None of them don't work on IIS Smtp Windows Server 2008 / 2008R2. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 has a newer version of IIS that has full integration with ASP.NET. This is the default mode. You can switch back to the older (ASAPI ASP.NET) by changing the application pool in IIS from "default" to "classic". That should make your app run like it does in Server 2003.

Without seeing more code and details, that's the only thing I can suggest.